# Completeing a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to complete a `UITableView` and i'm receiving an error on the final part of the code for one line.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

//ERROR IS IN THE LINE ABOVE ("anyobject" is not convertible to "UItableViewCell"

if (indexPath.section == 1) {
let (unit, availability) = myUnits[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = unit
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = availability
} else {
let (assessment, mark) = myAssessments[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = assessment
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = mark

}
return cell
}
```

Comment: You are missing an exclamation point after `as`. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the compiler that your cell is of the `UITableViewCell` class, which means downcasting using the `!` mark:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

Comment: Thank you, after adding ! I can succesfully run but it doesn't open the table view. It then goes to the code 
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

with a green line saying Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT. I believe its due to connecting the delegate and datasource to the view controller

Comment: Can you provide the logs from the debugger console?

Comment: Nothing goes into the debugger console after running it. When i click the next page to go to the tableview it then goes to NETWORK under Thread 1 then 12 main and shows the code that which is highlighted green i stated above. Do you have any idea of what this could be?

Comment: Put a break point before setting the labels and see what happens.

Comment: sorry im not sure what you mean. I'm not very talented with coding

Comment: You can read about the topic here: http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode